# Is this "differentiation map" uniquely determined by these properties?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set of all real-valued functions having their domain a subset of $\Bbb R$ which are at least differentiable on an open set, and for $f \in A$, let $U_f$ be the largest open set on which $f$ is differentiable. Let $B = \{ f \in A: \text{ Domain}(f) = U_f\}$, $C$ be the set of all real-valued functions having their domain a subset of $\Bbb R$, and $D: B \to C$ be given by $Df= f'$ (i.e. the derivative map of $f$).

Let $T: B \to C$ be a non-zero linear mapping which satisfies:

- If $g(U_g) \subset U_f$, then $T(f \circ g) = (Tf \circ g) Tg$
- $T(fg) = (Tf)g + f(Tg)$

Is it true that $T =  D$?

From the assumptions on $T$, we can prove that for any polynomial $p$, $Tp = Dp$, and consequently that for any rational function $q$, $Tq = Dq$. I don't know what can be done at this point. If we were considering the maps $T$ and $D$ as maps from $C^1(\Bbb R)$ to $C(\Bbb R)$, for instance, then we could've concluded that $T = D$ using density and continuity.

Comment: How do your assumptions rule out taking *Tf* = 0 for all *f*?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine they don't. Sorry, I'll add another assumption.

Comment: I take it that "open sets" here are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble yes, I'll add that as well.

Comment: Well, given that you took it as far as polynomials, it's very simple. See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44774/do-these-properties-characterize-differentiation/44778#44778

Comment: @ToddTrimble I saw that question and another related one, but the situation here is quite different. The set $B$ contains functions which may not even be continuously differentiable.

Comment: Oh sorry; you're right.

Comment: One more question, maybe nitpicky. Why do you write $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ (presumably the set of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) when $f'$ seems to be defined on only part of $\mathbb{R}$, like $U_f$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: How do you show that Tp = Dp when p is a polynomial? I can see how the "chain rule" implies Tx = (Tx)^2, but am not sure how to deduce that Tx=1 instead of Tx=0.

Comment: @GrahamCox the key is that for each $x_0 \in \Bbb R$ one can construct $g\in B$ and $y_0$ such that $g(y_0) = x_0$ and $Tg(x_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Personally I think without continuity one cannot assume this operator is the derivative mapping. It is possible to construct totally discontinuous functions, defined in odd manners, and taking what would be the equivalent of derivatives, except it isn't the derivative (I definitely know how to do this on $\mathbb{Q}$, I also think you can do it on $\mathbb{R}$ too). This leads me to doubt the possibility. Granted I can't give you a rigorous answer, this is just what's ringing in my head.

Comment: Nevermind, you are assuming continuity, just not a continuous derivative, this idea seems much more likely now.